# Pyodbc installation failed inside Virtualenvs(Pycharm)

Tags: python, pycharm

Im trying to install pyodbc inside Virtualenvs within pycharm.

i have no problem when i use normal command prompt inside windows :

[image]

but when i use the install command inside the pycharm console it gives me this error :

[image]

My project also based on django template. this is default new project setting :

[image]

Comment: Did you create venv along with site-packages?

Comment: @VaibhavJadhav at start of new project , i choosed for New Virtualenv.

Comment: Did you select site packages option in while creating the new environ?

Comment: @VaibhavJadhav I've added image of default project setting to question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the project settings check on `inherit global site-packages` and restart the pycharm and then try to install the package.